# Knockout checkboxes with array?

Tags: knockout.js

I know this topic has been addressed a few times but I'm having a bit of trouble here.  I have the following in my view:

```
    <!-- ko foreach: documents -->
    <div>
        <input type="checkbox" data-bind="checked: $parent.checkItem(documentId)" />
    </div>
    <!-- /ko -->
```

In my viewModel:

```
var checkItem = function (checkedItem) {
    debugger;
    window.selectedDocuments.push(checkedItem);
};
```

I'm using window because another resource needs access to this array.

Right now, when I load the page the checkItem is hit one time for each document, which I don't think it should.  I'm trying to monitor which documents have been selected, keeping an array updated (in this case, selectedDocuments).

Here's a fiddle with my attempt:

http://jsfiddle.net/PTSkR/36/

How can I make this work?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think all you should have to do is use a `checked` data-binding with the observable array. Knockout will update the observable array automatically when you check an item.

Also note that I added a `value` binding that binds the `value` of each checkbox to the `documentId`.

**View:**

```
<!-- ko foreach: documents -->
    <div>
        <input type="checkbox" data-bind="checked: $parent.selectedDocuments, value: documentId" />
    </div>
<!-- /ko -->

<!-- ko foreach: selectedDocuments -->
        <div>
            <span data-bind="text: $data"></span>
        </div>
<!-- /ko -->
```

**ViewModel:**

```
var selectedDocuments = ko.observableArray();

var viewModel = {
    documents: [{"documentId": "1"}, {"documentId": "2"}, {"documentId": "3"}],
    selectedDocuments: selectedDocuments
};
ko.applyBindings(viewModel);
```

**Example:** http://jsfiddle.net/PTSkR/37/

As a side note, I would avoid attaching properties to `window` if at all possible. You could use a [lightweight namespacing pattern](http://hangar.runway7.net/javascript/namespacing) or use a [simple pub/sub system with KnockoutJS](http://www.knockmeout.net/2012/05/using-ko-native-pubsub.html).

Comment: Wow, awesome.  Thanks Andrew.  "I would avoid attaching properties to window if at all possible." - why is that?

Comment: Thanks again man.  I just tried to implement pub/sub and I'm super close to getting it working, question posted here if you have time: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16307483/observable-arrays-with-knockout-publishing-subscribing

Answer (score 0):

You will want to bind your `checked` binding either against an observable or an observableArray.  When bound against an array, the `checked` binding with add and remove the `value` of the input from the array.

So, in your case, you could bind the input's `value` against the documentId  against an array, which would result in an array of ids.  Then, you can use a computed to create an array of the document's represented by those ids.

```
var viewModel = {
    documents: [{"documentId": "2"}, {"documentId": "3"}, {"documentId": "1"}],
    selectedDocumentIds: ko.observableArray()
};

//quick index to make lookup require less looping
viewModel.documentIndex = {};
ko.utils.arrayForEach(viewModel.documents, function(doc) {
   viewModel.documentIndex[doc.documentId] = doc; 
});

//computed to represent an array of the actual objects
viewModel.selectedDocuments = ko.computed(function() {
    return ko.utils.arrayMap(viewModel.selectedDocumentIds(), function(id) {
        return viewModel.documentIndex[id];
    });
});
```

Sample here: 
http://jsfiddle.net/rniemeyer/DCZKz/