# Observable arrays with knockout publishing/subscribing

Tags: knockout.js, publish-subscribe, single-page-application

I'm following this post:

http://www.knockmeout.net/2012/05/using-ko-native-pubsub.html

to allow one of my vms to communicate with the other.  One of my viewModels has an array that I need to expose to another viewModel.  If this array is not an observable, the method from the above post works just fine.

If the array is an observable array, publishedSelectedFolders is never populated.  I'm trying to figure out why; hopefully it's something silly I'm doing.

Here's my jsFiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/PTSkR/40/

If you uncomment the line in the vm, it works as expected (publishedSelectedFolders is populated as checks are ticked).  Why is this happening?

Code:

```
    /*
 * Pub/Sub (decouples VMs but lets them access each others' data)
 */
var postbox = new ko.subscribable();

ko.subscribable.fn.publishOn = function (topic) {
    this.subscribe(function (newValue) {
        postbox.notifySubscribers(newValue, topic);
    });

    return this; //support chaining
};

ko.subscribable.fn.subscribeTo = function (topic) {
    postbox.subscribe(this, null, topic);
    return this; //support chaining
};

/* Selection code */
this.publishedSelectedFolders = ko.observableArray().subscribeTo("SELECTED_FOLDERS");

var vm = {
    folders: ko.observableArray([{
        "folderId": "1"
    }, {
        "folderId": "2"
    }]),
    // folders: [{"folderId": "1"}, {"folderId": "2"}, {"folderId": "3"}],
    selectedFolderIds: ko.observableArray(),
};

vm.folderIndex = {};
ko.utils.arrayForEach(vm.folders, function (folder) {
    vm.folderIndex[folder.folderId] = folder;
});

/* monitors selections and publishes to the shell */
this.selectedFolders = ko.computed(function () {
    return ko.utils.arrayMap(vm.selectedFolderIds(), function (id) {
        return vm.folderIndex[id];
    });
}).publishOn("SELECTED_FOLDERS");

ko.applyBindings(vm);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `ko.utils.array...` helpers **do not** unwrap observables automatically (see [source on github](https://github.com/SteveSanderson/knockout/blob/master/src/utils.js#L50-L53)). So you need to pass them the already unwrapped arrays and not the `observableArray` directly.

So the error is in your `arrayForEach` call, where the correct usage is:

```
ko.utils.arrayForEach(viewModel.documents(), function(doc) {
   viewModel.documentIndex[doc.documentId] = doc; 
});
```

note the `()` at the end of the `viewModel.documents()`, and how you have used correctly the `viewModel.selectedDocumentIds()` in the `ko.utils.arrayMap`.

Your fixed [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mWXTs/).

Comment: Thank you.  I tried this in my project but it's not working and I can't reproduce the problem on jsFiddle.  In my project, 'folders' is an observable array of viewModels, each with a property folderId.  These were made from the ko mapping plugin.  Any idea what else could be going on?

Comment: Have you managed to find out what was the issue in your actual code?

Comment: Was just about to post back.  I just had to reference the properties as unwrapped observables - folder.id() instead of folder.id.  Thanks so much :)